# Checking if a string contains # with its original catcode

Tags: tex-core

At [comp.text.tex](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.text.tex/QHWWD8MZV70) the following scheme was suggested for testing if a string contains the parameter character with catcode 6.

```
\def\endcheck{\endcheck}
\def\second#1#2{#2}
\def\gobbletocheck#1\endcheck#2#3{#2}
\def\checkhash#1{\docheckhash#1\endcheck} 
\def\docheckhash#1{%
  \ifx#1\endcheck 
    \expandafter\second 
  \else 
    \ifx#1##% 
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gobbletocheck 
    \else 
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\docheckhash 
    \fi
  \fi 
}
```

This can be called as

```
\checkhash{abc#def}{YES}{NO} 
\checkhash{abcdef}{YES}{NO}
```

Obviously, as suggested by its author, this test fails if the string to test contains brace groups with the first two tokens identical, e.g.,

```
\checkhash{ab{cc}def}{YES}{NO}
```

Please can anyone suggest a better test? Please note that the catcode of the hash character must be 6, not 12.

An expandable solution will be beautiful but not a necessity.

Comment: Can we use e-TeX?

Comment: Yes, an eTeX solution is welcome.

Answer (score 13):

This is easy, but not expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\checkhash}{mmm}
 {
  \musa_checkhash:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \musa_checkhash:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { \cP. } { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\checkhash{abc#def}{YES}{NO}

\checkhash{abcdef}{YES}{NO}

\checkhash{ab{cc}def}{YES}{NO}

\checkhash{ab{c#c}def}{YES}{NO}

\end{document}
```

The output is

> YES
>   NO
>   NO
>   YES

The `l3regex` module of the `expl3` (LaTeX3 experimental) bundle furnishes regex  searches and replacements. In addition to a great part of the common regex machinery, it allows to take care of category codes. A character, character range or wild card can be preceded by a prefix telling what category code we want (these prefixes can be used both in the search and in the replacement text). The prefixes are

```
\cC \cB \cE \cM \cT \cP \cU \cD \cS \cL \cO \cA
```

corresponding, respectively, to control sequence, begin group (catcode 1), end group (catcode 2), math shift (catcode 3), alignment (catcode 4), parameter (catcode 6), superscript (catcode 7), subscript (catcode 8), space (catcode 10), letter (catcode 11), other character (catcode 12), active character (catcode 13). The missing codes can never reach the tokens that reach the mouth of TeX, so they don't have a prefix (escape, 0; end-of-line, 5; ignored, 9; comment, 14; invalid, 15). There is also `\cC` for denoting a control sequence.

We check, in the code, whether *any* character having category code 6 appears in the token list given as argument: the period is a wild card representing any character (actually token, in `l3regex`); preceding it with `\cP` means that only characters with category code 6 will match.

If only `#`<sub>6</sub> characters are to be considered, then the regex to use would be

```
\cP\#
```

Note that spaces in a regex expression are ignored; use `\`  (i.e. backslash and space) for denoting a space that is part of a regex.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this will only find explicit macro parameter characters (not implicit ones created by `\let\@sharp #`), because `l3regex` does not care about the `\meaning` of tokens.  Actually, I'm not 100% sure that `l3regex` is robust against receiving implicit macro parameter characters.

Answer (score 10):

As noted a test such as

```
 \ifx#1\endcheck
```

is true if the first two tokens of `#1` are equal. That part is easy to fix. When using `\ifx` tests always put the guard token first

```
 \ifx\endcheck#1
```

Now you only get bad result if the input token is `\endcheck` you can make that less likely by having a harder to type token as the guard token.

So this is an expandable test removing two levels of brace groups (not more, although it can be extended)

```
\def\endcheck{\endcheck}
\def\second#1#2{#2}
\def\gobbletocheck#1\endcheck#2#3{#2}
\def\checkhash#1{\docheckhash#1\endcheck}
\def\firstofone#1{#1}
\def\docheckhash#1{\expandafter\xdocheckhash\firstofone#1}
\def\xdocheckhash#1{%
  \ifx\endcheck #1%
    \expandafter\second 
  \else 
    \ifx###1% 
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gobbletocheck 
    \else 
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\docheckhash 
    \fi
  \fi 
}
```

This can be called as

```
\checkhash{abc#def}{YES}{NO} 

\checkhash{abcdef}{YES}{NO} 


\checkhash{ab{cc}def}{YES}{NO}

\checkhash{ab{#d}f}{YES}{NO} 

\checkhash{ab{{#d}}f}{YES}{NO} 

\bye
```

this reports YES NO NO YES YES

Comment: `\checkhash`, `\docheckhash`, and `\xdocheckhash` are removing one argument group each. Thus the following example with argument group nesting depth four fails: `\checkhash{{{{a#}}}}{yes}{NO}` -> `NO`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes s as noted above, the code doesn't work for arbitrary depth, you can easily increase the depth by adding more firstofone calls, removing brace levels to arbitrary depth whilst staying expandable is also possible but complicates th eloop perhaps more than needed.

Answer (score 9):

An expandable solution using `expl3`, which finds explicit and implicit catcode 6 tokens at any level of nesting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \musa_if_param:n #1 { TF }
  { \__musa_if_param:n { #1 ? } }
\cs_new:Npn \__musa_if_param:n #1
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1} { \prg_return_false: }
      {
        \tl_if_head_is_N_type:nTF {#1}
          {
            \tl_if_head_eq_catcode:nNTF {#1} ##
              { \prg_return_true: }
              { \exp_args:No \__musa_if_param:n { \use_none:n #1 } }
          }
          { \exp_args:No \__musa_if_param:n { \use:n #1 } }
      }
  }
\musa_if_param:nTF { 123 ~ \foobar } { \error } { }
\musa_if_param:nTF { 12 { { 3 } 4 # } } { } { \error }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\stop
```

Comment: It breaks with `! Argument of \use:n has an extra }` if space tokens are used, e.g. `\musa_if_param:nTF { ~ } { \error } { }`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Thanks.  Fixed, by first appending a non-`#` normal token.  This way, `\use:n` is always safe, may remove more than one space, and may remove braces, but we don't care about those anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an expandable plain TeX solution. Please let me know if it is foolproof.

```
\let\do\noexpand
\edef\x#1{\def#1\do\ifx##1\detokenize{macro parameter character}##2\relax}
\x\bcheckhash{\ifx\checkhash#2\checkhash}
\def\endcheck{\endcheck}
\def\gobbletocheck#1\endcheck#2#3{#2}
\def\checkhash#1{\gocheckhash#1\endcheck}
\def\second#1#2{#2}
\edef\x{%
  \def\do\gocheckhash##1{%
    \do\ifx\do\endcheck##1%
      \do\expandafter\do\second
    \do\else
      \do\expandafter\do\bcheckhash\do\expandafter\do\ifx
      \do\meaning##1{\relax}\detokenize{macro parameter character}\relax
        \do\expandafter\do\expandafter\do\expandafter\do\gocheckhash
      \do\else
        \do\expandafter\do\expandafter\do\expandafter\do\gobbletocheck
      \do\fi
    \do\fi
  }%
}\x
```

Tests

```
\edef\x{\checkhash{ab{cc}de}{Y}{N}}
\edef\y{\checkhash{ab{cc}#de}{Y}{N}}
```

Comment: It seems good, but it checks only at the outer brace level.

Comment: Something in Appendix D might apply (finding asterisks at any brace level in an expandable way).

Comment: App. D of the TeXBook or TeX by Topic? Which page?

Comment: The TeXbook, pages 375–376. However the check for a `*` at any group level is not expandable (and I guess it can't be).

Comment: @egreg: it is possible expandably.  See (untested) code in my answer.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: `\checkhash{ab\bcheckhash c}{\message{true}}{\message{false}}` shows `true` rather than `false`, because you are finding macro parameter characters by testing if their meaning contains `macro parameter character`, rather than starting with that.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Please what is `\bcheckhash` doing in the token list to be tested?

Comment: @AhmedMusa: You are asking if your solution is fool-proof.  It is not fool-proof, even in the absence of brace group, because it tests for the presence of a token whose `\meaning` contains `macro parameter character`, rather than for the presence of an actual macro parameter character.  `\bcheckhash` was just a convenient available example to break your code.  By the way, I can't remember well, but was it you who said you would learn `expl3` once it contained the expandable floating point parser?

Answer (score 2):

We can safely explore an infinite nest of brace groups by the following expandable scheme.

```
\makeatletter
\begingroup
\lccode`\&=1 \catcode`\&=7
\lccode`\*=1 \catcode`\*=11
\lccode`\?=1 \catcode`\?=8
\lowercase{\endgroup
  \gdef\if@func#1#2{\if@func@i#1x?#2*?}
  \gdef\if@func@i#1#2?#3#4?{%
    \csname @\ifx#1#3first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }
  \gdef\if@blank#1{%
    \csname @\ifcat?\detokenize\expandafter{\@gobble#1.}?%
    first\else second\fi oftwo\endcsname
  }
  \gdef\gobbletoendhashcheck#1&#2#3{#2}
  \gdef\checkforhash#1{\docheckhash@i#1&}
  \gdef\docheckhash@i#1{%
    \if@blank{#1}{%
      \docheckhash@i
    }{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\docheckhash@ii\expandafter
      \@cdr\detokenize{#1}\@nil?{#1}%
    }%
  }
  \gdef\docheckhash@ii#1?#2{%
    \if@func{##}{#2}{%
      \docheckhash@iii{##}%
    }{%
      \if@blank{#1}{\docheckhash@iii{#2}}{\docheckhash@i#2}%
    }%
  }
  \gdef\docheckhash@iii#1{%
    \if@func{&}{#1}
      \@secondoftwo
      {\if@func{##}{#1}\gobbletoendhashcheck\docheckhash@i}%
  }
}
\makeatother
```

Tests

```
\def\y#1{\edef\x{\checkforhash{#1}{Y}{N}}\typeout{\x}}
\y{a{}d}
\y{ab{{{{cc}}}}de}
\y{ab{{cc}}{{#}}de}
```

Comment: It is very often better to edit the previous solution rather than posting a new one.  A few comments on that one: (1) I suspect that you intended to wrap the code in `\lowercase`, otherwise the `\lccode` assignments are not needed; (2) The use of `\@cdr` fails if the argument of `\docheckhash` is blank (only made of explicit (32, 10) spaces), in particular `\checkhash{{}}` fails.

Comment: I think you forgot to save your edit: I am seeing the same code as yesterday (and the page says "edited yesterday").